# SQL DB2: Need to select all records belonging to a client having a unique value in column B (value = P)

Tags: sql, db2-luw

Need to select all records belonging to a client having a unique value in column B (value = P)

Here is my DB2 Table:

```
Name      Column B

David         P
David         P
Stacy         A
Stacy         A
Curry         A
Curry         P
Curry         P
Kevin         P
Kevin         P
```

Result expected:

> ```
> Name          Column B
> David         P
> David         P
> Kevin         P
> Kevin         P
> ```

Answer (score 1):

If there aren't any nulls in ColumnB you can use `NOT EXISTS`:

```
select t.* from tablename t
where not exists (select 1 from tablename where Name = t.Name and ColumnB <> 'P')
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=db2_11.1&fiddle=af0b57d24ad945514315694e6b4e2ea5).
Results:

```
>  NAME | COLUMNB
> ----: | ------:
> David |       P
> David |       P
> Kevin |       P
> Kevin |       P
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question, you seem to want:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.b = 'P' and
      not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.name = t.name and t2.b <> 'P');
```